# Creating a batch command to find and move many files

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here is the following issue I'm trying to deal with.

Here is my task I'm trying to do.
I have a folder that contains around 38K photo assets.  I want to be able to find multiple files within that directory and select them so I can move them into their own directories.  The file names are not in any sort of chronological order or this would be a fairly easy task.   To give you a better understanding of this let me try and create a simple visual for you on this.

```
IMAGEFOLDER
     3-2m.jpg
     1-2~5.jpg
     4-66-T-90.jpg
     4A-1~0.jpg
     2F1-1.jpg
     3B-1-1947-48.jpg
     4A-1.jpg
     5-1~5.jpg
     3A-1.jpg
```

My small sample set here is I want to find for example `4A-1.jpg`,  `4-66-T-90.jpg`, `3A-1.jpg` and stick them in another directory called 
`USN0001-05` (already created this directory locally on my PC via a `.bat` file).

I'm not good with Bat files whatsoever, but the only way I was able to create the folders I wanted was from another stackoverflow question posted on here.

I know that I will have to replicate this for every image inside the folder which is okay because I could just write it in Excel if it's as simple as just replacing the file name every time and doing the move for each folder on its own.

In theory what I'm trying to do is re-organize a folder structure for a photo gallery.

My folder structure is that the following files live here:
`C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Documents10003`

```
Need to move files to various folders created here
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Documents\New folder\SOMEFOLDERNAME
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Documents\New folder\SOMEFOLDERNAME2
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Documents\New folder\SOMEFOLDERNAME3
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Documents\New folder\SOMEFOLDERNAME4
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Documents\New folder\SOMEFOLDERNAMEetc...
```

Here is an example of the Photo to Album relationship or rather the Photo to Folder relationship

```
   filename,Album Title
FW-1-1006.jpg,USAF 0001
FS-2-1006.jpg,USAF 0002
3-1-J-3_35.jpg,USAF 0003
4-8-K-4_0.jpg,USAF 0004
5-1.jpg,USAF 0005
ACC-1051.jpg,USAF Units A
HQ-USAF-1001.jpg,USAF Units B-O
PACAF-PLANS-1021.jpg,USAF Units P-T
3605-2.jpg,USAF Units U
192-66.jpg,USAF Units V-Z
training_Command_.jpg,Army Air Forces Shoulder Sleeve Insignia
FTW-14-2013-06-1001.jpg,Columbus AFB
FTS-23-2004-01-1001.jpg,Fort Rucker Helicopter Training
FTW-47-2007-14-1001.jpg,Laughlin AFB
66-B-Moody.jpg,Moody AFB
Reese_68C.jpg,Reese AFB
FTW-80-2008-06-1001.jpg,Sheppard AFB
FTW-71-2000-11.jpg,Vance AFB
82-1988-05-1001.jpg,Williams AFB
3560-1968F-1.jpg,Webb AFB
TS-392-2011-06-1001.jpg,Vandenberg AFB ICBM Training
TPS-08-B-1001.jpg,USAF Test Pilot School
09-01-1.jpg,USAF Weapons School
186-11-08-1.jpg,Training Classes-Misc
303-326.jpg,USAF Competitions (Non-Unit Specific)
44-311.jpg,USAF Exercises &amp; Wargames (Non-Unit Specific)
90-156.jpg,USAF Aircraft Patches (Non-Unit Specific)
522-162.jpg,"USAF Armament, Missiles &amp; Other Equipment (Non-Unit Specific)"
JOIST-1001.jpg,USAF Satellites &amp; Other Space
BAER-1011.jpg,USAF Air Force Bases/Stations
f106_exp_wpn_ins.jpg,USAF Awards/Recognition
Air_Battle_Manager-Morale_28V229.jpg,USAF Career Field/Speciality Patches
6-1.jpg,USAF 0006
7-721.jpg,USAF 0007
8-2_1.jpg,USAF 0008
9-321.jpg,USAF 0009
10-1.jpg,USAF 0010-0015
16-1.jpg,USAF 0016-0020
FTS-23-1001.jpg,USAF 0021-0025
26-1.jpg,USAF 0026-0030
31-1.jpg,USAF 0031-0035
37-2.jpg,USAF 0036-0040
41-1.jpg,USAF 0041-0045
46-1.jpg,USAF 0046-0050
53-1.jpg,USAF 0051-0055
57-1.jpg,USAF 0056-0060
61-1.jpg,USAF 0061-0065
67-1.jpg,USAF 0066-0070
71-1.jpg,USAF 0071-0075
76-6.jpg,USAF 0076-0080
82-1.jpg,USAF 0081-0085
89-1.jpg,USAF 0086-0090
95-1.jpg,USAF 0091-0095
96-1.jpg,USAF 0096-0099
101-1.jpg,USAF 0100-0110
111-1.jpg,USAF 0111-0120
121.jpg,USAF 0121-0130
131.jpg,USAF 0131-0140
142.jpg,USAF 0141-0150
151-1.jpg,USAF 0151-0160
162.jpg,USAF 0161-0170
171-1.jpg,USAF 0171-0180
181-1.jpg,USAF 0181-0190
191.jpg,USAF 0191-0199
232-1.jpg,USAF 0200-0299
301-1.jpg,USAF 0300-0310
317-1.jpg,USAF 0311-0320
321-1.jpg,USAF 0321-0330
331-1.jpg,USAF 0331-0340
343.jpg,USAF 0341-0350
354-1.jpg,USAF 0351-0360
389-71.jpg,USAF 0361-0370
371-1.jpg,USAF 0371-0380
303-316.jpg,USAF 0381-0390
391-1.jpg,USAF 0391-0399
405-Det2.jpg,USAF 0400-0410
413-1.jpg,USAF 0411-0420
421-1.jpg,USAF 0421-0430
431-1.jpg,USAF 0431-0440
444-1.jpg,USAF 0441-0450
460-1.jpg,USAF 0451-0460
465-1.jpg,USAF 0461-0470
480-1.jpg,USAF 0471-0480
482-1.jpg,USAF 0481-0490
496-1.jpg,USAF 0491-0499
509-1.jpg,USAF 0500-0525
526-1-E-5_15.jpg,USAF 0526-0550
555-1.jpg,USAF 0551-0575
596-1.jpg,USAF 0576-0599
602-1.jpg,USAF 0600-0699
701-1.jpg,USAF 0700-0799
825-1.jpg,USAF 0800-0899
911-1.jpg,USAF 0900-0999
1550-1.jpg,USAF 1000-1999
2727-1.jpg,USAF 2000-2999
3553ccts~0.jpg,USAF 3000-3999
4441-1.jpg,USAF 4000-4999
5021-1.jpg,USAF 5000-5999
6147-2.jpg,USAF 6000-6999
7108-1.jpg,USAF 7000-7999
199-CCTS.jpg,USAF 8000-8999
Joint_HQ_Far_East_Cmd_282-piece29.jpg,Far East Command
Pacific_Command_28V129.jpg,Pacific Command &amp; U.S. Pacific Command
Alaskan_Command_28V529.jpg,Alaskan Command
EUCOM.jpg,European Command
Caribbean_Defense_Command.jpg,Caribbean Command
USACOM_28V229.jpg,Atlantic Command &amp; U.S. Atlantic Command
US_European_Cmd_28var29~0.jpg,U.S. European Command
US_Strike_Cmd_28V329.jpg,U.S. Strike Command
USSOUTHCOM_-_Partnership.jpg,U.S. Southern Command
US_Readiness_Cmd_28V329.jpg,U.S. Readiness Command
US_Central_Cmd_28T-II2C_V229.jpg,U.S. Central Command
USSPACECOM_Spec_Activities_Nuclear_C2.jpg,U.S. Space Command
US_Special_Ops_Cmd_28gaggle29.jpg,U.S. Special Operations Command
USTRANSCOM_28V429.jpg,U.S. Transportation Command
US_Strategic_Cmd_ST21_28error29.jpg,U.S. Strategic Command
US_Joint_Forces_Cmd.jpg,U.S. Joint Forces Command
US_Northern_Cmd_JTF-Civil_Support.jpg,U.S. Northern Command
US_Africa_Cmd_28V229.jpg,U.S. Africa Command
Combined_Field_Army_28ROK-US29.jpg,United Nations Command
North_American_Aerospace_Def_Cmd_28V829.jpg,NORAD
NATO_AWACS_Special_Vehicle.jpg,NATO (&amp; related)
1st_Allied_Airborne_Army.jpg,World War II era
MATS_28V229.jpg,Military Air Transport Service
3510-1972D-1.jpg,Randolph AFB
432-30.jpg,USAF Aircraft Patches-Fighter-Manufacturer-A-M
82-4~0.jpg,USAF Aircraft Patches-Fighter-Manufacturer-N-Z
81-66.jpg,USAF Reproductions
39-56.jpg,USAF Unknowns
BB-62-NEW_JERSEY-321.jpg,USN BATTLESHIPS
AKA-103-RANKIN-1.jpg,USN AMPHIBIOUS
PACIFIC_MISSILE_RANGE_FACILITY__BARKING_SANDS.JPG,USN NAVAL AIR STATIONS/BASES
DoD_28V229.jpg,SECDEF / OSD
JCS_28V329.jpg,Joint Chiefs of Staff
NEACP_28JCS_V429.jpg,NEACP/NAOC
SON-1-V-4_65.jpg,USAF Special Missions
21-20~0.jpg,USAF HOLDING
VMAQ-1-1051.jpg,USMC 1-99
VMFA-122-1006.jpg,USMC 100-199
211-10.jpg,USMC 200-299
311-4-US-5_15.jpg,USMC 300-399
452-3.jpg,USMC 400-499
VMFAT-501-1101.jpg,USMC 500-599
623-1.jpg,USMC 600-699
HMM-764-1.jpg,USMC 700-799
1-1~10.jpg,USN 0001-5
9-326~0.jpg,USN 0006-10
11-1~10.jpg,USN 0011-19
22-11~1.jpg,USN 0020-29
33-1~4.jpg,USN 0030-39
42-2~3.jpg,USN 0040-49
52-4~1.jpg,USN 0050-59
64-3~4.jpg,USN 0060-69
75-1-z-1946.jpg,USN 0070-79
81-1~0.jpg,USN 0080-89
93-1~6.jpg,USN 0090-99
100-1~2.jpg,USN 0100-119
122_insignia.jpg,USN 0120-139
144-1~2.jpg,USN 0140-159
163-1~3.jpg,USN 0160-179
192-1m.jpg,USN 0180-199
203-1.jpg,USN 0200-224
303-11.jpg,USN 0300-599
673-1-NAS-Atlanta2CGA.jpg,USN 0600-699
702-1-NAS-Dallas2CTX.jpg,USN 0700-799
811-1-NAS-Minneapolis2C_MN.jpg,USN 0800-899
912-1-NAS-South-Weymouth2CMA.jpg,USN 0900-
Mobile_Sea_Range_28Blue29.JPG,USN UNITS A-M
Naval_Air_Warfare_Center__28Phantom_F-429.jpg,USN UNITS N
Pacific_Missile_Test_Center_28Flight_Test29a.jpg,USN UNITS O-Z
10003.JPG,USN AIRCRAFT (NON UNIT SPECIFIC)
Cast_Glance.jpg,"USN ARMAMENT, MISSILES &amp; OTHER EQUIPMENT (NON UNIT SPECIFIC)"
914-1.jpg,USMC 900-
AAFES_28V129.jpg,Agencies
AFKN_Radio-TV.jpg,Field Activities
NPTR.jpg,DRUs &amp; Other Joint Organizations
Armed_Forces_School_of_Music.jpg,Schools
Joint_Base_Pearl_Harbor-Hickam.jpg,Bases
123-31~0.jpg,"Wars, Confrontations, Named Ops, etc."
NATO_ACC_Northern_Wedding-United_Effort_82.jpg,Exercises
SOJTF-A_NSOCC-A_PPP~1.jpg,Joint Task Forces
OAS_IAPF.jpg,OAS
MFO_28V329.jpg,MFO
Combined_Security_Transition_Cmd.jpg,Other
UN_28V229.jpg,UN
NORAD_Top_Scope.jpg,Competitions &amp; other events
JSTARS_28var29.jpg,Aircraft
WS-Laser_JDAM_Boeing.jpg,Missiles/Munitions
NNSA_28DOE29.jpg,Government Organizations
40___8.jpg,Veteran Organizations
POW-MIA.jpg,Commercial
FTG-479-2012-02-1001~0.jpg,NAS Pensacola
3640-1971-01.jpg,Laredo AFB
Malmstrom13-05zz.jpg,Malmstrom AFB ICBM Training
100-NV-2.jpg,USAF Aircraft Patches-Missions
90-131.jpg,USAF Aircraft Patches-Hours
3-2-Barracuda.jpg,SS 1-99
261-1-MINGO-ZZZ.jpg,SS 200-299
315-1-SEA-LION-ZZZ.jpg,SS 300-399
400-1zz_Sea_Devil.jpg,SS 400-499
522-1zzz-Amberjack.jpg,SS 500-599
600-1zzz-Theorore_Roosevelt.jpg,SS 600-699
19-213.jpg,USN-UNKNOWN
16-1-Tringa.jpg,USN SUBMARINE TENDERS
30-1-San_Pablo.jpg,USN MISCELLANEOUS
Op_URGENT_FURY_repro.jpg,REPRODUCTIONS
NATO_PFP_UTP_1993.jpg,UNKNOWNS
```

Comment: It's not so clear what you're asking. Do you want to **select** files somehow via a batch file? Let me ask...isn't easier with some sort of _true_ programming Language? PowerShell? C#?

Comment: Not really a SO answer, but for such tasks, Total Commander is king!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is in someway move files from one directory to another.  given the fact there are 30K assets I can't do this by hand.  I know the directories I want to place them in but I don't know how to write that command to move them and or FIND them.

Comment: Is there any logic in the names? How would **a computer** tell them apart?

Comment: I have unique file names yes.  I have an association in an excel file that says for example 3-2m.jpg maps to SOMEFOLDERNAME1  and 4A-1.Jpg goes to SOMEFOLDERNAME3 and so on.  What I'm hoping for is to be able to somehow unbenounced to me is have some Bat file (I think) that has many lines on it that looks inside the master folder of images and says move this here or move that there

Comment: Would this be doable with an xcopy command?

Comment: Use `move /y <source_file> <destination_folder>` to move your files, if this is what you're looking for. Otherwise, try to explain why your attempts aren't working.

Comment: Its not that my attempts aren't working, I just don't know how to write that batch file to do this.  I'm a front end developer with minimal chops on batch files, I just am unsure how to even begin to write that file.  It seems easy but for someone who never touches these types of files I'm a little lost :(

Comment: The file that maps filename to folder is what is needed here.  Write it to a CSV file and post a few lines onto your question.

Comment: ive gone ahead and added more insight to it per your request @foxidrive

Comment: Okay @foxidrive I've now updated it as you asked

Comment: Ok, use that with the batch file in the answer I posted.  Test it first though.  You might also want to do a search and replace in the CSV file for `&amp;` and replace it with `&` and take further note that some folders will not be created as they contain poison characters, like `/` JFTR These are all poison characters `: / \ | < > ? *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on some sample files.

With a CSV file like this in the same folder as the files, and the batch file below in the same folder also:

```
file,target
FW-1-1006.jpg,USAF 0001
FS-2-1006.jpg,USAF 0002
3-1-J-3_35.jpg,USAF 0003
4-8-K-4_0.jpg,USAF 0004
5-1.jpg,USAF 0005
```

Then this code should handle the folder creation and file moving:
if the folders already exist then that is fine.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (file.csv) do (
   echo moving "%%~a" to "%%~b" folder
   md "%%~b" 2>nul
   if exist "%%~b\" move "%%~a" "%%~b" >nul
)
echo done
pause
```

This will help to rename the folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (
set "folder=%%a"
ren "%folder%" "!folder:(10),,,,,,,,,, =!"
)
```

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM!!!! created each of the folders and put them in the correct folders!  Ive been trying to do this for a week now! Thank you so much @foxdrive!

Comment: It may not have done them all - there were some poison characters in the target folders.  But I'm glad that it helped you.

Comment: Ahh I can do clean ups not a big deal!

Comment: I edited it once more - just to deal with folders that can't be created.  Also If you REM out the echo line then it will be faster to move the files.

Comment: @FoxDrive  This worked just as expected created all 208 albums some photos didn't get placed but I have to assume they weren't in the list for some weird reason.  One question I did have is that all the folders that were created have (10),,,,,,,,,, at the end of each folder.  Not a huge deal to just remove them 1 and a time but any idea why that would have happened?

Comment: Inside your CSV file will be the extra characters - Open it in Notepad and you will see them.  I can't think of any other reason for them being there if the code wasn't changed.  The folder names can be renamed easily - see the edited answer above for an extra batch file.  Get the text to be replaced right, with any spaces before and after, and it should work well.  The text to be removed is between the `:` and `=`